# Is there any way to have a nav link navigate to a specific section of another page in html/css WITHOUT specifying the div id?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm pretty new to html, css, and js. I have an online portfolio, and my "work" page is a scroll under my intro/landing page.

However, when trying to navigate to "work" from any other page, it just navigates to the top of the entire page, which is the landing page for my website. (even though the link is "index.html#work", it doesn't automatically scroll to that section when jumping to that page from somewhere else.) I also don't like using these kinds of links as it makes it a new url, which can lead to unexpected issues when the OS's back button is pressed.

Is there any simple way to utilize scrollTo in vanilla js to scroll to this specific section after it is navigated to with this work nav link? Or any similar way to automatically jump to this section of the page with a link from another page?

Thanks.

My index.html#work link does not navigate to the work section when clicked from another page on my website.

Comment: If it's not navigating automatically, you probably have some JS that's overriding it. You should fix that.

Comment: I would double-check that the id exists on the page to rule that out, even though it seems obivous. By default, it should work but if it's not, then something must be either missing or stopping it from doing that.

Comment: yes, I believe JS is overriding it. I was just curious if theres any other simple way to do this because I don't like how it changes the URL

Comment: Why not create a dedicated sub-page for your work / portfolio?